# In PHP, can I use and Include or Require inside a Function within a Class?

Tags: php

We are changing old PHP/MySQL code to new MySQLi OOP code and it would be easier to INCLUDE the new code in the same location in the existing code. However, some of the code resides as a Function inside a Class and I am not sure if I can just plug in the include.

For example, the old code is:

```
class get_names
    {
      function __construct()
         {
            $temp = mysql_query("select first_name last_name from name_table
                    where member_id=".$_SESSION['member_id']);
            $names = mysql_fetch_array($temp);
          }
     }
```

Changed to:

```
class get_names
    {
       function __construct()
          {
             include("GetNames.php");
          }
     }
```

Can this be done in this fashion? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whilst you can include code it is _really_ bad style. Just think of readability, maintainability, debugging, ... You have to adjust the code anyway for error detection and handling. Do yourself a favor and do a good job. You will thank yourself in a few months time...

Answer (score 1):

You should rather [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) your classes and use [FQNS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) (Fully Qualified Name Space). This way you don't need to be checking what files you should include each time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you?  Yes.

Should you?  No.  This is not a good style and will be harder to maintain.  A better solution would be to write a function in a separate file, include that file, and call the function.

GetNames.php:

```
function getNames()
{
    $temp = mysql_query("select first_name last_name from name_table
            where member_id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['member_id']));
    return mysql_fetch_array($temp);
}
```

Class file:

```
require_once 'GetNames.php';

class get_names
{
   function __construct()
      {
         $names = getNames();
      }
 }
```